# Eclipse plug-in that gives list of variables like notepad++ does?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any type of Eclipse plug-in that brings down a list of variables like notepad++ does?

such as I have varbiales like:
z1
z2
z3
z4

and when I press z a drop drop kind of box comes up with every variable starting with z? if that makes any since.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Eclipse has a feature called **Content Assist**. To use it for your example, type `z` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Note that Content Assist can fill in many other things, such as names of classes, methods, and much more.

Answer (score 0):

That should be available in stock Eclipse - try pressing `ctrl+space` to bring up Eclipse's auto-complete list.